# Git not correctly showing status of other remotes

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

See image below of my current git tree as viewed from SouceTree on my local machine.

[image: git tree]

Up until recently, I could see where my Production and Staging servers were at (Red and Green in the image, respectively). Whenever I did a pull on my production or staging server, it would would show their new positions on the tree locally.

Recently, they've stopped updating, even though I know that `production/master` and `stage/staging` are up-to-date. That is, my `green/staging` should be at `origin/staging` and my `red/master` should be at `origin/master`.

How can I fix it so that its correctly showing me the status of my other repositories?

Comment: "Whenever I did a pull on my production server"... not sure if that's imprecise wording, or reflects a misunderstanding you've been working with. Your local repo's reflection of the remote's state is updated when you locally fetch (or pull) from the remote.  Merely the fact that the remote changes is not seen by any of your local tools until you fetch (or pull) locally

Comment: Right; I didn't mean it would instantaneously update, but a fetch isn't updating the status of those remotes

Comment: So you know that the ref for a branch on the remote has moved, but a `fetch` doesn't move the corresponding remote branch ref.  Does the `fetch` command produce unusual output?  Do you know that you're getting new objects from the remote (if any exist that you don't already have locally)?

Comment: My suspicion is this would be a bad remote configuration.  If it used to work and nothing changed that would obviously break it (like moving the remote to a new URL), then one possibility would be the refspec config.  (If for some reason the refspecs don't start with `+`, then a history rewrite on the remote could cause the ref to stop updating on the local. But that seems like a reach here.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger To test, I created a new branch and committed a file. I pushed that to origin, but its not showing up on the origin repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be related to an issue with SourceTree specifically

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-8264